# Why does adapter.add crash?

Tags: java, android, adapter

I have an adapter for a list view and every time it reaches the .add line, it crashes, and I already set it an arrat adapter and a text view and everything, so why does it crash?

Comment: What does it crash with?

Comment: You'll need to post some code.

Comment: And detail what you mean by "crash", does it throw any exception?

Answer (score 2):

Without giving your code it's very difficult to check what could be wrong.

The following link gives you a tutorial on setting up a listview http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html, however it implements ListActivity.

In case you implement only Activity your code should look like that

```
package my.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lvList; // the listview
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; // the adapter responsible for the rendering
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>(); // the list of items
    String myString = "Text to add"; // the text to add

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lvList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        lvList.setAdapter(adapter);

            //add the text to the list of items
        listItems.add(myString);

            //tell the adapter that the list have change and the
            //rendering should be refreshed
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Actually the example I gave is for String but you can do it for Integer or any class you created.

Answer (score 2):

I had problem similar like you, load more data with older devices, with older android version... and i'm first added

> objAdapter.addAll(loadMoreArray);

and call

> objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

but that was not good solution, older device crash app if you add new list of data in objectAdapter. But solution was load your new data in new list and add new list of data in old list

> arrayListOfData.addAll(newArrayListOfData);

and call

> objAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Hope i helped...